# Why does setting window.location.href not stop script execution

Tags: javascript, redirect

The following code changes the location to www.bing.com regardless of wether redirect is 1 or any other number. If redirect is 1, it logs "is redirecting" and then redirects to www.bing.com. My best guess is that when href is set a change-event is triggered, but it takes some ticks before it executes. Meanwhilethe first line of code after is still executed. Or? do anyone what happens?

```
if (redirect == 1) {
    console.log("is redirecting");
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}

window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
```

Comment: Interesting! MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) that "Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document will be loaded using the URL as if location.assign() had been called". Do you get the same behaviour with .assign()?

Comment: @DanFromGermany - I did indeed solve it with an else, but it bugs me, that I don't know why it continues

Comment: @EmilVikström - Same thing happens with location.assign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the behaviour is undefined.

When you set the expected url to `window.location.href`, the current page will actually be in the `dying` state. And the result of the code written after that is simply unpredictable.

Comment: But why not stop code execution while in dying state?

Comment: @Bildsoe Because in some cases, you might want to send some data to server when the page is *dying*.

Comment: @Bildsoe because you might want events to still trigger when right before changing the location

Comment: @Tresdin - I know i'm sidetracking here but, will it wait for the data to finish before handling the page-death event?

Comment: @Bildsoe Again, it's unpredictable. You shouldn't rely on any code written on dying state. Anyway, I personally think it will.

Comment: @Bildsoe between initiating the redirect (setting the `.href` property) and actually doing the redirect, you want events to be triggered (like firing Google Analytics for example).

Answer (score 8):

You are setting a property, not calling a method, the difference is important:

```
window.location.href = "something";
```

Javascript works asyncronous and event based,
that means the browser doesn't check for the window location changing right when you set the property, but some unpredictable time later.

Sometimes you want exit-events to be triggered or fired when the location changes.

When you compare this to the HTTP location header, the behaviour is the same.
Sometimes you want for example PHP scripts to continue even you send the location change header.

Comment: Javascript is not async by default.

Comment: @d1du Depends on what exactly we are talking about. From a specific point of view, nothing is async at all and nothing is really sync. In this case `window.location.href` is executed async, so commands after `window.location.href` are still executed, until the browser starts to move on to the new location.

Answer (score 2):

That's because everything after the `if` is executed as well, but it looks like there's a difference between Chrome and FF (haven't tested in IE).

Example code:

```
var redirect = 1;

if (redirect == 1) {
    console.log("is redirecting");
    document.location.assign('https://developer.mozilla.org/');
}

alert('go');
document.location.assign('https://www.bing.com/');
```

In Chrome 'go' is alerted, and you're redirected to bing.com.
In Firefox, 'go' is alerted, but you're redirected to MDN.

I think, the best thing to do is to wrap the other stuff in an `else`.

Comment: Yes, but really the question is, why does it continue script execution - why not just halt script execution and redirect "instantaneous"?